# How can I post to Twitter without loading my timeline?

Tags: twitter

I've recently stopped visiting Twitter during my lunch break at work due to the risk of [inappropriate content appearing on my timeline while at work](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/27221/68427).

I'm looking for a direct URL to the "Compose a Tweet" window, which would allow me to post to my Twitter profile directly, rather than having to use the main website.

**Is it possible to post to Twitter *without* displaying tweets from users I follow?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same URL as Stack Exchange in its *Share* dialogue.

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet
```

This will load a *compose tweet* page that closes automatically once you clicked the *Tweet* button. You cannot add images in that page.